# Usar tag <map> em uma imagem de forma responsiva

Tags: html5, css3

Boa noite,

Preciso linkar um pedaço de uma imagem, mas este link tem que funcionar de forma responsiva. Quando visualizo a página num celular, perco o mapeamento.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

O que eu fiz?
No link à seguir, tem um jeito de fazer o mapeamento, mas não entendi como aplicar na minha página.
http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

Answer (score 0):

É necessário utilizar a bitlioteca jQuery (como por exemplo a do [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)) para o plugin funcionar.
Em seguida então pode adicionar a biblioteca de mapeamento referenciada do [GitHub](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

Insira as duas bibliotecas antes do encerramento da tag `</head>` do seu site:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
```

E em seguida então já dentro do `<body>` adicionar o código restante, apontando para o elemento pretendido:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.minhaImg[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});

// código abaixo apenas para teste
$('area').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicado!');
});
```

```css
.minhaImg {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>

<img class="minhaImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ly6F.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sol">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercurio">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Aqui tens também um exemplo no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/x28kmgjo/) onde podes arrastar as bordas da janela de resultados para uma melhor visualização da demonstração.

Comment: @Chun, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas, quando testo em meu celular por exemplo, a área mapeada deixa de funcionar. O que eu quero dizer é o seguinte: No tamanho normal, ok. Ao reduzir, o ponto marcado é fixo... preciso tornar ele responsivo, para acompanhar a redução da imagem. No exemplo que coloquei no Fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/z2zyhefw/], não consigo fazer com que o sol fique marcado sempre, independente da imagem.

Comment: Complementando a informação, tem uma diferença entre nossos códigos. Preciso usar a classe `img-responsive` para que a imagem reduza ou aumente, de acordo com o dispositivo.

Comment: @HebertRichard Eu testei no meu celular e está funcionando corretamente. Sim, é provável que os códigos não coincidam, eu não sei qual era o seu código porque você não o adicionou à sua pergunta, então eu criei um esboço de exemplo. Mas basta apenas trocar a classe `.minhaImg` para a classe desejada. [Aqui tem outor exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/x28kmgjo/1/)